# Can't get title from the first RICHEDIT60W child in Lync

Tags: pywinauto

This code I do not get the first available RICHEDIT60W:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().connect(class_name='CommunicatorMainWindowClass')
window = app.window(class_name='CommunicatorMainWindowClass')

window.NetUINativeHWNDHost.NetUIHWND.print_control_identifiers()

print()
rich_edit = window.NetUINativeHWNDHost.NetUIHWND.NetUICtrlNotifySink.RICHEDIT60W
print("rich_edit:", rich_edit.WindowText())
```

Console:

> ```
> Control Identifiers:
>
> NetUIHWND - ''    (L162, T378, R562, B957)
> ['', '1', 'NetUIHWND', '0']
> child_window(class_name="NetUIHWND")
>    | 
>    | NetUICtrlNotifySink - ''    (L186, T408, R537, B425)
>    | ['2', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink1', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink0']
>    | child_window(class_name="NetUICtrlNotifySink")
>    |    | 
>    |    | RICHEDIT60W - '///'    (L186, T408, R537, B425)
>    |    | ['RICHEDIT60W0', '///RICHEDIT60W', 'RICHEDIT60W1', '///', 'RICHEDIT60W']
>    |    | child_window(title="///", class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
>    | 
>    | RICHEDIT60W - '///'    (L186, T408, R537, B425)
>    | ['RICHEDIT60W0', '///RICHEDIT60W', 'RICHEDIT60W1', '///', 'RICHEDIT60W']
>    | child_window(title="///", class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
>    | 
>    | NetUICtrlNotifySink - ''    (L184, T548, R515, B562)
>    | ['3', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink2']
>    | child_window(class_name="NetUICtrlNotifySink")
>    |    | 
>    |    | RICHEDIT60W - 'qwerty'    (L184, T548, R515, B562)
>    |    | ['RICHEDIT60W2', 'qwerty', 'qwertyRICHEDIT60W']
>    |    | child_window(title="qwerty", class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
>    | 
>    | RICHEDIT60W - 'qwerty'    (L184, T548, R515, B562)
>    | ['RICHEDIT60W2', 'qwerty', 'qwertyRICHEDIT60W']
>    | child_window(title="qwerty", class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
>    | 
>    | NetUICtrlNotifySink - ''    (L162, T378, R162, B378)
>    | ['4', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink3']
>    | child_window(class_name="NetUICtrlNotifySink")
>
> rich_edit: qwerty
> ```

[image: lync]

By elements of the list, the first had to be "///" and not "qwerty"

What is the problem?

How to get the item with "///"?

Comment: I can take a look later, but it's better to use `Application(backend="uia")` for Lync. Read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to make so:

```
import pywinauto
window = pywinauto.findwindows.find_element(title_re='Microsoft Lync.*')
child = window.children()[3]
print(child.rich_text)  #  ///
```